# Watson Conversation example case sensitivity

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

I am trying to use the Watson REST APIs to add examples to an Intent for Watson. Before I call the [Create Endpoint](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#create_example) I call the [Get Example endpoint](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#get_example) with the intent and example.

When I call the Get Example endpoint with the word "fine" it returns a 404. Then when I try to Create an example it returns a 400 response

`{"error":"Unique Violation: The value \"fine\" already exists"}`

This is happening because we already have an example "Fine" (notice the first letter is capital).

How can I prevent this? Are there best practices to store examples in all lower case? Or should I just catch the 400 exception and look at the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Violation error means it didn’t update. So you can certainly check for that to take action. Although I personally recommend looking for the related item first to avoid the error.

Coding convention recommendations. These formats are used to easily recognize what is referenced in code and if an identifier is missed.

For example is this below an intent, entity or context variable?

```
accountingPayBillCode
```

### Intents

All caps, spaces as underscores.

```
#ACCOUNTING_PAY_BILL
```

The examples (questions) should be entered untouched as how you received them. Do not attempt to fix spelling / grammar errors.

Example:

> I need to pay my bill. Can yuo help me?

### Entities

CamelCase with first word capitalized. The value should be all lowercase, and avoid multiple words (but must be meaningful).

```
@AccountDetail:code
```

The reason to avoid multiple words as the value is that you can end up with something like this.

```
@AccountDetail:(part number)
```

It makes it more prone to a mistake.

Synonyms should also be stored all in lower case.

### Context variables.

Always reference using the `$` prefix. Use camelCase with first character lowercase.

```
$accountCode
```

Comment: Ok, when we add examples is it recommended to add them in their normal case? Does case matter in examples?

Comment: Knew I forgot something. :) Updated.